# DownloadAsBytes in mongodb gridfs creating empty file

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-web-api, gridfs

I am uploading a file to webapi which saves a file(pdf's & word documents) to mongodb gridfs(v 2.6.1)

**webapi code**

```
 var file = Request.Files[0];
 var fileName = file.FileName;
 var fileType = file.ContentType;
 var document = blabl.UploadFile(fileName, fileType,ReadFully(file.InputStream));
```

**convert incoming stream to bytes**

```
public static byte[] ReadFully(Stream input)
{
   using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
   {
       input.CopyTo(ms);
       return ms.ToArray();
   }
}
```

**GridFs code**

```
var bucket = new GridFSBucket(_database, new GridFSBucketOptions
{
    BucketName = bucketName,
    WriteConcern = WriteConcern.WMajority,
    ChunkSizeBytes = 1048576
});

var id = bucket.UploadFromBytes(fileName, source, options);
return id;
```

**Code to download**

```
var bucket = new GridFSBucket(_database, new GridFSBucketOptions
{
    BucketName = bucketName
});

return bucket.DownloadAsBytes(id);
```

**WebApi**

```
HttpResponseMessage result = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
result.Content = new ByteArrayContent(data);
result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
{
    FileName = "MyPdf.pdf"
};
result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");
return result;
```

**UI code**

```
$.ajax({
    url:'path',
    type: 'GET',
    responseType: 'arraybuffer',
     success: function (data)
     {
      var link = document.createElement('a');
       if ('download' in link) 
        {

            try {
             var blob = new Blob([data], { type: contentType });
             var url = urlCreator.createObjectURL(blob);
              link.setAttribute('href', url);
              link.setAttribute("download", filename);
              var event = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
              event.initMouseEvent('click', true, true, window, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
              link.dispatchEvent(event);

             } catch (ex) 
             {
               console.log(ex);
             }
         }
     }

  });
```

Post download the file is empty.
I would be really greatfull if you guys point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i had changed the webapi code as below

```
HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage = new HttpResponseMessage();
httpResponseMessage.Content = new ByteArrayContent(data.ToArray());
httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = fileName;
httpResponseMessage.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
return httpResponseMessage;
```

Also, i forgot that i had a delegating handler which is changing the response.